# Adding days in date using QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, date

I'd like to create a new field adding 10 days in a date (string format) in QGIS; using the Field Calculator.
For example, in the `field_1` there is `22/02/2021`, in `field_new` it should become `04/03/2021`.

Maybe, I should convert date in number, as you can see in Excel.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is type of the date field? String or Date?

Comment: "field_1" is a string, also "field_new" will be a string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
format_date(to_date("field_1",'dd/MM/yyyy')+to_interval('10 Days'),'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

First you need to convert your string to a date (the `to_date()` function), so you can add a datetime interval. The `format_date()` is needed, because the result of `+ to_interval()` will return a datetime format. So you convert the result back to a date only and use your previous date-format as string (dd/MM/yyyy instead of yyyy-MM-dd).

Answer (score 6):

For string-typed target field:

```
to_string( to_date( "field_1" , 'dd/MM/yyyy' ) + to_interval( '10 days' ) )
```

[image]

---

For date-typed target field:

```
to_date( to_date( "field_1" , 'dd/MM/yyyy' ) + to_interval( '10 days' ) )
```

[image]