# add 2 hours to a varchar column containing timestamp

Tags: qgis, timestamp, time-zone

I have a qgis varchar column that is used to store timestamp in this format : HH-MM-SS.

I would like to add 2 hours to every entries.

08:30:45 would become 10:30:45.

Is there a way to convert these without converting the field to timestamp then back to varchar?

Comment: This post here might be useful for your needs: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388074/adding-days-in-date-using-qgis-field-calculator